# Variation of coupon collector problem with distinct coupons in each type

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I am interested in yet another variation of the coupon collector problem. Specifically, we have an urn with $n_i$ "distinct" coupons of type $i$, where $i = 1,\ldots, K$ (for example, a type can be thought of as a color but within that color the coupons are numbered). The goal is to sample sufficiently with replacement to get a collection having at least $m_i$ distinct coupons from type $i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, K$ (any $m_i$ out of the $n_i$ different coupons within that type would work). Note that this is different from the variation in:

N. Shank and H. Yang, "Coupon Collector Problem for Non-Uniform Coupons and Random Quotas," Electronic J. of Combinatorics 20(2) 2013

since the coupons here are numbered and the analysis needs to ensure the $m_i$ coupons from type $i$ are distinct. So the question is:

For a given number of samples $n$, what is the probability that we achieve the requirement above (i.e., obtain $m_i$ distinct coupons from the types $i = 1,\ldots,K$). Upper and lower bounds would also be useful. Also, what is the expected value of the number of samples $E[N]$ to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Two answers were provided by @joriki and esg at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825115/drawing-at-least-that-many-distinct-balls-of-each-color

Comment: please note the correction of the typo (missing $s^k$, observed by joriki) in the answer below

Comment: I corrected another typo. Let me know when anything needs more explanation.

Comment: Thank you @esg. It's a bit involved so I am trying to read the [Shank and Yang] paper carefully then will let you know if I am having difficulties. I also wonder if this can be easily extended to the case where the probabilities of the different coupons within each type are different? I guess in this case, one will have to sum over the probabilities of the sets corresponding to the surjection mappings (I dunno if this is tractable).

Comment: I also do not understand the bracket notation $[t^k]$ @esg. What exactly does that mean? What does it mean for the number of mappings to depend on t ? Also how do you go from the generating function to the probability expression?

Comment: (1) $[t^k] F(t)$ denotes the coefficient of $t^k$ in the power series $F(t)$ (with obvious generalization to several variables), the operator $[t^k]$
is frequently called  "(extraction of) the $k$-th coefficient  (operator)"                  
(2) For example,  $[t^k] (e^t-1)^r$ is the number that you get
when you expand $(e^t-1)^r$ as a power series of the variable $t$ and take the $k$-th coefficient - it's just a number and does not depend on $t$ in any way. (3) I've answered the last question in the text

Comment: Got it. Thank you @esg. I guess for the example of $(e^t - r)^r$ that coefficient would be $r! S(k,r)/ k!$  where $S(k,r)$ is the Stirling number. One last question: Is the extension to non-uniform probabilities even within the type straightforward using this approach? In such case, the probabilities of different sets with the same number of items are not equal (since which items matter), so I believe it may not be a simple counting argument.

Comment: It's easy to write down the joint generating function (analogue of the proposition below). But if the probabilities are not uniform within a type the summation gets more complicated (conatining sums over elementary symmetric functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same notation as the cited article (so that the results can be directly compared), so 
consider an urn which for $i\in\{1,\ldots n\}$ contains $x_i\geq 1$  distinguishable coupons of type $i$, altogether
$X_n:=x_1+\ldots+x_n$ coupons.

Coupons are drawn with replacement from this urn until (for each $i$) $m_i$ (where $1\leq m_i\leq x_i$) mutually different coupons
of type $i$ have been drawn.

Let $m:=(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ and $T(m)$ the random time at which this happens, and let $p_{x_i}(m_i,t):=\sum_{k=0}^{m_i-1}{x_i \choose k}\,t^k$.

Let $Y_1(k),\ldots,Y_n(k)$ be the random variables  $Y_i(k):=$ number of **different** coupons of type $i$'' that have been drawn
 at  "time" $k$.

I use generating functions and start from the following basic

**Proposition**
*The generating function of (the joint distribution of)
$Y_1(k),\ldots,Y_n(k)$ is given by:*
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\, t_1^{Y_1(k)}\ldots t_n^{Y_n(k)}=\frac{k!} {X_n^k}[t^k]  (1+(e^t-1)\,t_1)^{x_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+(e^t-1)\,t_n)^{x_n}
\end{equation*}

**Proof** Let $j_1+\ldots +j_m\leq k$.
Clearly 
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_1(k)=j_1,\ldots,Y_n(k)=j_n)=\frac{1}{X_n^k}\cdot {x_1 \choose j_1}\cdots {x_m \choose j_m}\cdot Sur(k,j_1+\ldots+j_m)$$
where $Sur(k,r)$ denotes the number of surjective mappings from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ onto $\{1,\ldots,r\}$. It is known that
$Sur(k,r)=k!\,[t^k]\,(e^t-1)^r$ (since a such a surjective mapping corresponds uniquely to an ordered partition of
$\{1,\ldots,k\}$ into $r$ non-empty subsets, and  $e^t-1$ is the exponential generating function for non-empty sets). The assertion 
about the g.f. follows. **End of proof.**

(I)  The distribution of $T(m)$

Since $\{\,T(m)\leq k\}=\{\,Y_1(k)\geq m_1,\ldots,Y_n(k)\geq m_n\,\}$ the above gives 
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(T(m)\leq k) =\frac{k!} {X_n^k}[t^k]  (e^{tx_1} -p_{x_1}(m_1,e^t-1))\cdot\ldots\cdot(e^{tx_n} -p_{x_n}(m_n,(e^t-1)\,)
\end{equation*}

From g.f. to probability:
we have to compute \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(\,Y_1(k)\geq m_1,\ldots,Y_n(k)\geq m_n\,)
&=\sum_{j_1\geq m_1,\ldots, j_n\geq m_n} \mathbb{P}(Y_1(k)=j_1,\ldots,Y_n(k)=j_n)\\
&=\sum_{j_1\geq m_1,\ldots, j_n\geq m_n} [t_1^{j_1}\ldots t_n^{j_n}]\mathbb{E}\, t_1^{Y_1(k)}\ldots t_n^{Y_n(k)}
\end{align*}
Since the function after $[t^k]$ is a product of factors each containing only one of the $t_i$ variables we can treat these factors individually.
E.g. to account for $\mathbb{P}(Y_1(k)\geq m_1,...)$ we have to sum up all the coefficients $[t_1^j]$ with $j\geq m_1$ of the first factor. 
We may  equivalently sum up all coefficients (i.e. put $t_1=1$) and subtract the sum of the first $m_1$ coefficients. Doing that 
"inside" (and leaving the $t^k$ extraction "outside" (coefficients may be extracted in arbitrary order)) we arrive at the factor $e^{tx_1}-p_{x_1}(m_1,e^t-1)$, etc..

(II) The expectation of $T(m)$

Finally, using $\mathbb{E} T(m)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \mathbb{P}(T(m)>k)$ and writing ${k! \over X_n^k} =X_n\,\int_0^\infty s^k e^{-X_ns}\,ds$ leads to

$$\mathbb{E}(T(m))=X_n\int_0^\infty \big(1-\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-p_{x_i}(m_i,e^s-1)\,e^{-x_i s}\right)\big)\,ds$$