# Coupon Collector Score

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector

Suppose you have a non-uniform coupon collector problem. But, rather than quotas, each coupon gives you points. There are $n$ different groups of coupons, and the probability of receiving a coupon of each group is $p_i$. There are $N_i$ distinct coupons in group $i$ with each coupon within a group equiprobable. The number of points you receive for getting a new coupon in group $i$ is:

$$\dfrac{N_i}{p_i(N_i-k_i)}$$

where $k_i$ is the number of coupons you have already gathered from group $i$. So, obviously, the points for the first coupon of each group is just $\dfrac{1}{p_i}$. But, once you get more coupons from each group, each coupon is worth more.

**Question:** What is the expected number of points you will have after collecting $m$ distinct coupons?

I attempted to try to brute force the expected value of the score, but I was not having much luck. And when I tried to calculate it by monte carlo simulation, I wound up with a fairly large variance.

I can easily calculate the expected value for points after drawing one coupon. That is just the number of groups. And from there, I think for 2 coupons among $n$ groups, I think the expected number of points will be:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \dfrac{p_ip_j\left(\begin{cases}1 & i\neq j \\ \tfrac{N_i-1}{N_i} & i = j\end{cases}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{p_i} + \dfrac{1}{p_j}\begin{cases}1 & i \neq j \\ \tfrac{N_i}{N_i-1} & i = j\end{cases}\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\left(\begin{cases}1 & k \neq i \\ \tfrac{N_i-1}{N_i} & k = i\end{cases}\right)}$$

This just looks like a nightmare to calculate even for two coupons. Any advice on how to make this a bit easier to calculate? I am looking at similar coupon collector problems, such as the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879927/variation-of-coupon-collector-problem-with-distinct-coupons-in-each-type), but the addition of points for coupons is really throwing a wrench into my attempt at creating a generating function. I was hoping to expand my attempt at calculating the expected points from two coupons into a generating function, if I could see a pattern. I did not.

Comment: Only one thing is unclear. You say there are only $N_i$ coupons in group $i$. What happens after you have gotten all the coupons in a group $j$? Afterward, is the probability of drawing from group $j$ zero, and the other probabilities are rescaled?

Comment: When you get a coupon, it can be any coupon, but you only earn points if it is the first time you've drawn that specific coupon. So, if you have all the coupons from group $j$, you may keep drawing those coupons, but you will never get any new points for them.

Comment: So, essentially, yes, you can look at it the way you said. The probability that you earn points will get rescaled as you mentioned.

Comment: Got it; to choose each coupon, you random choose a group where $P(\text{group $i$})=p_i$, then you uniformly randomly choose a coupon from that group, with replacement. I was confused because I was assuming no replacement.

Comment: Is every coupon in a group equiprobable?

Comment: @user yes. I updated the question.

Comment: Does "after collecting $m$ distinct coupons" mean that the collecting process stops as soon as the collection contains $m$ coupon types?

Comment: The collecting can continue as long as you want. The question is about how many points I can expect to have accumulated at various instances throughout the collection, where I don't care how many coupons I've collected, only how many distinct coupons.

Comment: I did not ask how many coupons should be collected, I asked about the condition to stop the collecting process. It is also not clear what you mean by "distict coupons" in the question, because you have both distinct "groups" and distinct coupons inside each group. So, what does $m$ precisely mean?

Comment: Be aware: if you write a comment without addressing a user, nobody will be notified about the comment.

Comment: @user I am not sure what word to use besides "distinct". Think of them like Pokémon. Gotta catch them all. There are common Pokémon, rare Pokémon, shiny Pokémon, legendary Pokémon, and each group has a percent chance you will encounter them. But, the Pokémon in each group are all distinct. I hope this is a better explanation. I will try to think of other examples if you are not familiar with Pokémon.

Comment: You can try to explain using this example, when you stop collecting the items.

Comment: @user With Pokémon, "Gotta catch them all!" So you stop when you have one of every distinct Pokémon from every distinct group. $$N = \sum_{i=1}^n N_i \\ m \in \{1,2,\ldots N\}$$ So, $m$ is any stopping point when you have some number of distinct Pokémon, not caring which group they are from. The groups just help determine probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I initially misread the post; this answer computes the expected number of points after $m$ draws, not after getting $m$ distinct draws.

Call a group *dead* if all of its coupons have been chosen previously, and *alive* otherwise.

---

**Lemma** If there are currently $a$ alive groups, the expected number of points from your next coupon is $a$.

*Proof:* Suppose you have already $k_i$ coupons from the $i^{th}$ group, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $X$ be the number of points from your next coupon. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $G_i$ be the event that the next coupon is from group $i$.

$$
E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n P(G_i)E[X\mid G_i]=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\cdot 
\left(\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{N_i-k_i}{N_i}\times \frac{N_i}{p_i(N_i-k_i)} & k_i < N_i
\\
0 & k_i=N_i
\end{cases}\right)
=\text{#}\{i\mid k_i<N_i\}
$$

---

Now, let $X_t$ be the number of points you get on draw number $t$, for $t\in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Then
\begin{align}
E[X_t]
  &= E[\text{# alive groups before turn $t$}]
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n P(\text{group # $i$ alive before turn $t$})
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{N_i}\{\text{$j^\text{th}$ coupon in group $i$ not yet chosen}\}\right)
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} (-1)^{j-1}\binom{N_i}{j} \left(1-p_i\frac{j}{N_i}\right)^{t-1}
\end{align}

The last equation is a routine application of the principle of inclusion-exclusion. Therefore, if you draw $m$ coupons total, the expected number of points is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^mE\left[ X_t\right]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} (-1)^{j-1}\binom{N_i}{j} \sum_{t=1}^m\left(1-p_i\frac{j}{N_i}\right)^{t-1}
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} (-1)^{j-1}\binom{N_i}{j} \frac{1-(1-p_ij/N_i)^m}{p_ij/N_i}
\\&= \boxed{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{N_i}{p_i}\sum_{j=1}^{N_i} (-1)^{j-1}\binom{N_i}{j}\frac1j\cdot  \left(1-\left(1-p_i\frac{j}{N_i}\right)^m\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is a great explanation if I was looking for the expected number of points when $m$ coupons are collected. I'm looking for the expected number of points when $m$ distinct coupons are collected. How does that change the problem? I suspect it changes the problem as you initially thought where it is collecting coupons without replacement.

Comment: @SlipEternal Hmm, I do not know how to solve it in that case. By the way, you should edit your question to clarify that this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Maybe this is the solution after all. I can determine the expected number of coupons needed before I have $m$ distinct coupons, then use your solution to determine the expected number of points achieved with that number of coupons drawn. This should get me "close enough" for what I'm doing, even if it is a little off.